# Android: ScrollView doesn't work in case of full screen

Tags: android

I want to scroll my ScrollView when keyboard appears.
In case of normal screen everything is ok 
but in case of full screen ScrollView doesn't work.
There is my code below.

---

MyActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

---

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1.0">

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:text="@string/user_name"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/user_name_signup_edit"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:text="@string/password"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_signup_edit"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="@string/confirm_password"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/confirm_password_signup_edit"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:text="@string/email"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email_edit"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="@string/name"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name_edit"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="language"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/language_spinner"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Sign up"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

1. List item

Answer (score 0):

Use `wrap_content` in ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497

Bit late perhaps but even if it's just for clarity/future people coming across this.